# Spring ArgumentResolver to get pathvariable map and

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, annotations

this my method signature

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/article", "/article/{id}", "/article/{name}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET,
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
 
  public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> get(@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVarsMap, @RequestParam(value="test") MultiValueMap<String, String> test, @RequestBody(required=false) JsonNode requestBody )
```

I want to make this into

```
public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> get( MyStructure mystr)
```

where `MyStructure`  will have `@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVarsMap, @RequestParam(value="test") MultiValueMap<String, String> test, @RequestBody(required=false) JsonNode requestBody` inside of it.

I know that I have to use custom resolvers and implement `resolveArgument`. One of the examples i saw did `(Map<String, String>) httpServletRequest.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE)`. But im not sure how to get it to work. Can i create `MultiValueMap` and `RequestBody` inside MyString ?

In another place, I see that the recommendation is to use

```
@Nonnull
protected final Map<String, String>   getUriTemplateVariables(NativeWebRequest request) {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, String> variables =
        (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(
                URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE, SCOPE_REQUEST);
return (variables != null) ? variables : Collections.<String, String>emptyMap();
}
```

so im a bit confused on how should i be implementing this

Comment: That won't work as those annotations aren't allowed on fields only parameters.

Comment: Out of curiosity, wouldn't it be easier to understand the code if you created three separate endpoints? What is the reason to combine them in one method?

Comment: @kapstom - not sure what u mean. we have tons of endpoints. dozens of them infact. each endpoint needs path variables, request params,  request body and headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `@PathVariable` , `@RequestParam` and `@RequestBody` can only be annotated on the method parameters , so there are no ways for you to annotate them on the object fields.

The codes of the existing `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that resolve the values for these annotations also assume these annotation are annotated on the method parameters ,that means you also cannot simply delegate to them to resolve the value for your request object.

Your best bet is to simply reference the corresponding `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` for each annotation and copy the related codes to your implementation.

- For `@PathVariable` , it is resolved by `PathVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver`
- For `@RequestParam` on `MultiValueMap` , it is resolved by `RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver`
- For `@RequestBody` , it is resolved by `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` . Internally , it works with a list of `HttpMessageConverter` to read the HTTP request body. As you are now using Jackson to read the request body , you only need to focus on `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for simplicity.

It is easier than I expected. There following implementation should be a good starting point for you.

First define `MyStructure` class :

```java
public class MyStructure {
    public Map<String, String> pathVariables;
    public MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParameters;
    public JsonNode requestBody;
}
```

And implement `MyStructureArgumentResolver` :

```
public class MyStructureArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

        private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter;

        public MyStructureArgumentResolver(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter) {
            super();
            this.messageConverter = messageConverter;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
            return MyStructure.class.isAssignableFrom(parameter.getParameterType());
        }

        @Override
        public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

            MyStructure request = new MyStructure();

            request.queryParameters = resolveQueryParameters(webRequest);
            request.pathVariables = resolvePathVariables(webRequest);
            request.requestBody = resolveRequestBody(webRequest, parameter);

            return request;
        }

        private MultiValueMap<String, String> resolveQueryParameters(NativeWebRequest webRequest) {
            // resolve all query parameter into MultiValueMap
            Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = webRequest.getParameterMap();
            MultiValueMap<String, String> result = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(parameterMap.size());
            parameterMap.forEach((key, values) -> {
                for (String value : values) {
                    result.add(key, value);
                }
            });
            return result;
        }

        private Map<String, String> resolvePathVariables(NativeWebRequest webRequest) {
            Map<String, String> uriTemplateVars = (Map<String, String>) webRequest.getAttribute(
                    HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);

            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(uriTemplateVars)) {
                return new LinkedHashMap<>(uriTemplateVars);
            } else {
                return Collections.emptyMap();
            }
        }

        private JsonNode resolveRequestBody(NativeWebRequest webRequest, MethodParameter parameter)
                throws IOException, HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {

            HttpServletRequest servletRequest = webRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
            HttpInputMessage inputMessage = new ServletServerHttpRequest(servletRequest);

            MediaType contentType;
            try {
                contentType = inputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType();
            } catch (InvalidMediaTypeException ex) {
                throw new HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException(ex.getMessage());
            }
            if (contentType == null) {
                contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM;
            }
            Class<?> contextClass = parameter.getContainingClass();

            JsonNode body = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();

            if (messageConverter.canRead(JsonNode.class, contextClass, contentType)) {
                body = (JsonNode) messageConverter.read(JsonNode.class, inputMessage);
            }

            return body;
        }
    }
```

Then register `MyStructureArgumentResolver` :

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter;

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(new MyStructureArgumentResolver(messageConverter));
    }
}
```

And use it in the controller method :

```java
@RequestMapping(value = { "/test/{name}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> test(MyStructure request) {

}
```

Comment: thanks.please also consider to accept my answer if it is useful to you as i spent much time in writing this answer to help you

Answer (score -3):

```
@PostMapping("/get")
public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> get( @RequestBody MyStructure mystr){...}
```

When call this api, fill in params in request body, send body as application/json. Refer to this sample: [sample project](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-5/spring-requestbody)